# Xcode Autolayout How to centre uitextfield with fixed width that can adjust for smaller screens

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I can't seem to form how the constraints will work, so in Descriptive terms:

- the textfield is horizontally center to the container
- the textfield is 100 points offset from the top layout guide
- the textfield is 370points wide.
- if the container shrinks in width smaller than 370 points it will adjust proportionally
- if the screen goes wider the text field does not resize but stays at 370 points

I can more or less define constraints for most of them except for the ability to constrain its width automatically if the screen shrinks in width for smaller screen sizes.

Some pointers would be good

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a leading and trailing constraint to your textField with a lower priority. And simply add a width constraint that can be <= 370.

Comment: Based on the details the asker provided, I don't think this answer is correct (it's actually reversed). See my answer for what I mean.

Comment: Well i just tried it, and it seems to be working as i expect it to on 5S and iPad simulators! Maybe i misunderstood the problem!

Comment: Actually, I take back what I said. I misread your answer and missed the `<` in the last part. So you are correct as well! This is the other way to achieve the same result.

Comment: Thanks, this works, don't really understand how the lower priority impacts it though, but interesting I never tried that.

Comment: When constraints conflict with each other, the one with the lower priority breaks. Think of it like this: You want a MAXIMUM width of 370 AND at the very least, some distance from the sides. This brings up two scenarios, one that the the width is huge and one in which it isn't. In the case when the width is small, the textfield's width goes down as its set to `<=` and leading and trailing don't break. When the screen width is huge, the width max's out at 370 and since leading and trailing have a lower priority, they break as they will try and stretch the textField to a width more than 370.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
let textField = UITextField()
view.addSubview(textField)
textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

// center horizontally
textField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
// 100 from top layout guide
textField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true

// make sure textfield width never exceeds the superview width
textField.leftAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
textField.rightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true

// give the textfield its default width, notice the lowered priority which allows this constraint to be broken when needed to satisfy the above constraints
let widthConstraint = textField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 370)
widthConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh
widthConstraint.isActive = true
```

Comment: Wont having a lower priority on the width constraint cause it to break when screen width is huge? According to the question, shouldn't the width always remain 370 at maximum?

Comment: The constraint will only be broken if it has to. On a bigger screen, the `leftAnchor` and `rightAnchor` constraints are still satisfied and will not break the width constraint. So no, this should work perfectly and satisfy all of the conditions you listed. Just try it and see.